# How to go to quickfix window?

Tags: vimscript, quickfix

I know there is `:copen` command which opens `quickfix` window but it doesn't immediately switch to it(till it open). How can I wait for it to be sure my next commands in script would be executed in `quickfix`?

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem. You shouldn't have to wait for anything--the next commands in your script should be executed in the quickfix window. Perhaps you could include an example of something that isn't working as you expect it to. I tried a experiment with the following three lines in a script: `copen`, `set modifiable`, `put='abcde'`. I then opened vim, sourced that script file, and observed the expected result that the quickfix window contained the line `abcde`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function that I use to ensure the Preview window is open and has focus. I like this window to be in the first tab, if you don't want that then your logic will vary accordingly.

I have a function that is mapped to hotkeys that fire off builds of different flavors; this function is called right before I execute `:make` with my desired options.

```
function! EnsurePreviewWindow()
    if ! &previewwindow          " don't do this in the preview window
        tabfirst
        silent! wincmd P         " jump to preview window
        if ! &previewwindow      " if we still aren't there...
            0tabnew
            setlocal switchbuf=useopen
            execute "copen" (&lines / 3)
            set previewwindow
        endif
        silent! wincmd p
    endif
endfunction
```